# Do I need to have a request in API route handler in Next.js when I pass params?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have an API route handler for GET request:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(req: NextRequest, { params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
    const { id } = params;
    try {
        return NextResponse.json({
            body: {
                success: true,
                id: id,
            }
        }, {
            status: 200,
        })
    } catch (error) {
        return NextResponse.json({
            success: false,
        }, {
            status: 400,
        })
    }
}
```

It works and when I run it, it gives response with status 200. But when I remove the request, it gives me an error 500:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET( { params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
    const { id } = params;
    try {
        return NextResponse.json({
            body: {
                success: true,
                id: id,
            }
        }, {
            status: 200,
        })
    } catch (error) {
        return NextResponse.json({
            success: false,
        }, {
            status: 400,
        })
    }
}
```

Even though when I hover over req in parameters, it says `'req' is declared but its value is never read.`. Here's the screenshot:
[image]

So, why do I need to have request in parameters?

I'm using Next.js 13.4.16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Next.js API routes, the `req` parameter represents the incoming HTTP request object. Even if you're not directly using it in your API route handler, it still needs to be present in the function signature.

The reason for this is that Next.js API routes are built on top of the concept of serverless functions. When a request is made to your API route, the framework passes the incoming request to your handler function as the `req` parameter. This allows you to access information about the incoming request if needed, such as headers, query parameters, and request body.

If you remove the `req` parameter from the function signature, you are essentially telling Next.js not to provide the incoming request object to your handler. This results in the error you're encountering, as Next.js expects the function to accept the incoming request object.

So, even if you're not using the `req` parameter directly in your handler logic, it's still required to be present in the function signature for Next.js API routes to work correctly.